# vector library errors while using

Tags: c++, vector

I am learning about vector library and I have wrote this simple program about vector but I get 61  errors while compiling.

here is my code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    system("color 0B");

    std::vector<int> s;
    s.push_back(3);
    s.push_back(4);
    std::cout << s[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << s[1] << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and here is some  of errors that I  get and I don't know why?

```
Code    Description                                       File   Line
C2059   syntax error: ','                                vector  461
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'                vector  462
C3646   '_Val_types': unknown override specifier         vector  504
```

and many other erros...

and here is the source code of vector file from line 460 to line 464 and the two first errors are at line 461 and 462

the vector file code form 460 to 464 :

```
  typename _Alty::const_pointer,
  typename _Alty::reference,
  typename _Alty::const_reference> >::type,
  _Val_types;
};
```

Comment: What happens if cut the program to the bare bones and remove the windows-specific stuff to get down to [just the `vector` and a bit of IO](https://ideone.com/7Tv6kA)?

Comment: It's most likely that you are not using a C++ compiler to compile the file. There is a command line option /TP to force the compiler to compile the file as a C++ file no matter what the file name extension is. You could change the file name to a known C++ extension, such as .cpp, or try the /TP option.

Comment: Please show how exactly you are compiling. Preferrably compile with a commandline and show that. Or show your makefile. Or show anything from your IDEs configurations which might concern compiling. I want to know about the C standard version used by the compiler and which one is used by the code. I.e. I want to see everything looking like `-std11`.

Comment: Focus on the first error – a tiny error early on can cause immense amounts of later errors that aren't actually errors. Look for it in the Output window (the Error List isn't very useful, despite being there by default) and add it to your question.

Comment: @RSahu I doubt you'll see "unknown override specifier" from anything other than a C++ compiler.

Comment: @molbdnilo msvc isn't actually a C compiler, it just has some reluctant support for it. I wouldn't be surprised if it spat out C++-flavoured error messages for C syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The program is fine. My best bet is that you have inadvertently modified the vector header file around line 461 - if that is the first error you are encountering.

Are using Visual Studio? Check the Build Output window to see which error comes first and then double-click on that error to take you to the source code line. Maybe you'll spot some character that you have typed that does not belong there.

Comment: I have also changed  the code  to a simple code without declaring any object of vector and just including the vector library using this command " #include <vector>"  
but  this time I just get two first error that I mentioned above ( error line 461 and 462)

Comment: @meysamimani Could you post the source code lines 460 - 463 of the vector header file or do you notice any character in line 461 (i.e. a comma) that should not be there?

Comment: I have added to the question the lines of vector file form line 460 to line 464 folks

Comment: @meysamimani The comma at the end of `typename _Alty::const_reference> >::type,` looks out of place although I can't find the code snippet in the VS2017 vector header. You could try to copy your header file to a local folder, remove the comma and try to include that file for a test. If that does not work, what are your C++ dev tools?

Comment: Hi I have copied the header file to a local folder and remove the comma at line 461  and saved that file then  I have added that header file to my project but I got the same errors ...  I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I have tried the same with VS2015 but using a local copy of the `vector` file seems to cause compiler errors. I can find the exact code snippet for lines 460-464 in the VS2015 header but there is no comma after `type` in my case and the snippet starts at line 455 for me. It still looks to me as if the `vector` file is corrupt. Options are to try and modify `vector` in place or re-install. Your program, as originally posted, works fine for me in VS2015 also..

Comment: I have uninstalled  Visual Studio 2015 and install it again and write now it works . thanks all folks